# Rails 4 Countdown timer

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hi im trying to implement a countdown timer in a rails 4 application. i came across keith woods plugin from a similiar question http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html. the problem is getting a simple countdown timer to work as i cant find any simple examples in rails 4. all i want to do is add a countdown timer when a competition is created a timer starting from 10 days to appear like = days:hours:mins:sec

I downloaded the countdown package and added the *= jquery.countdown.css to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

i added //= jquery.countdown.js to my app/assets/javasript/application.js and i added both the jquery.countdown css and js files in my app/views/layout folder. i also have the gem 'jquery-rails' gem in my gem file

do i put my function in my competition.js.coffee file 
i have

```
$(function () { 
$('#until2d').countdown({until: '+2d'});
});
```

and call it in my competition view like

```
<div id="until2d"></div>
```

my app/views/competition show.html....where i want timer to appear

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p>
  <strong>Prize:</strong>
  <%= @competition.prize %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @competition.Date %>
</p>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_competition_path(@competition) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', competitions_path %>
<h1>Timer</h1>
<div id="until2d"></div>
```

my views/layouts/application.html.erb file where i put appropiate tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Timer</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.countdown.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

my app/assets/javascript/application.js file looks like

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= jquery.countdown.js
```

If anybody could tell me if im on the right track or point me to a simple tutorial i would appreciate it thanks

Comment: Did you check to see that your competition code is included on the page?  Are there any javascript console errors?  The basic setup looks like it should work properly.  As a sidenote, if you're not going to use coffeescript, you might as well just call that file compeition.js.

Comment: Hi Mr Rogers iv added my competition show code where i want timer to appear. im getting the following error in my competion.js file ExecJS::ProgramError in Competitions#show                                        [stdin]:5:3: error: reserved word "function"

Comment: Try changing your competition.js.coffee code to `coffeescript` or save it as a different filename (`competition.js`) and remove the coffeescript file.  That error is the Rails coffeescript compiler trying to read your "javascript" and expecting "coffeescript"

Comment: Hi that got rid of the error alright but the timer is not appearing im just getting the heating timer do u think my function is alright

Comment: I don't see the issue.  I got it to work here http://cdpn.io/CtJfF Again, i'd look at the javascript on the page and make sure your function is there.  Have you got a `require_tree .` in your application.js?  open up a browser and make sure it's loaded your competition.js source file - just because it was compiled doesn't mean it got loaded.  If all that works, try adding a console log in that file to validate that you're in there.

Comment: Hi i just edited my question i already had require_tree included in my application.js file im not sure why timer isnt appearing for me must be something small wrong are u using the exact same function as me in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your application.js file to:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.countdown.js 
//= require_tree .
```

You were missing `require` in front of the jquery.countdown.js and you probably need it to come before your code.

If this is the problem, you probably should have seen something in your Javascript console like "[Object] does not have method countdown" or something that would indicate the issue.  Also, if you look at your javascript source list (in a browser developer tools or in the source page) you should see jquery.countdown.js listed (assuming you're running in development mode - because in development mode, the asset pipeline serves up all the javascript separately so that you can debug these kinds of issues).

#### update

After reviewing the full code base, it was a combination of mis-placed javascript files and some bad javascript (javascript with coffee script comments mixed in).  The fix above is probably the basic fix, but the other items will be hard to share here.  For anyone interested, there is a pull request that moves some files around and does a bit of cleanup that solved the issue.  https://github.com/Bob-sheehy/timer/pull/1

Comment: Hi i taught that was it but unfortunately still cant get the timer to appear on the page. i shutdown web brick and tried again still no luck any other ideas thanks for spotting that missing require

Comment: I just noticed another issue with your layouts.  If you've included the js and css files in application.js and application.css (under assets), you don't need to *re-declare* them in the applications layouts.  you should be able to remove the <script> and <link> tags that you've put at the top of the body section.

Comment: i am not getting any errors at all at the minute. when i remove the link and script tags from layout/application.html the text just appears on the top of my competition/show.html.erb. just wondering should i include any of the other files that come with the plugin in my files i only added jquery.countdown.js and css

Comment: Well, i'm at a loss here.  Without looking more closely at the whole setup... it sure looks like things should work.  Is there a publicly availble url that I could hit?  or a git repo i could look at?

Comment: hey Mr rogers thanks for ur help il work a bit more on trying to fix it and il put a link to my github if i dont get it

Comment: I sent a pull request with the fixes.  I outlined the issues that i found.  Basically, you probably should read some more about the Rails asset pipeline and how it works.  The root of the issue was that you were not properly including the javascript on the pages.  I made some notes accordingly.  Check out the pull request and you'll see the changes I made.  Hopefully it'll be clear.  https://github.com/Bob-sheehy/timer/pull/1.  Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your time and help i will take your advice and read about rails asset pipline

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is not a Turbolinks issue?

Try this to initialise your code:

```
jQuery(document).on("ready page:load", function() {
  $(function () { 
    $('#until2d').countdown({until: '+2d'});
  });
});
```

Since Turbolinks does not do full page changes on get requests, the `document.ready` event never fires.

Comment: Hi Mohamad it tried adding your code still cant get timer to appear on page any other ideas